# pandas series mean値がnan値になる

Tags: python, pandas

kaggle Home Credit Default Riskのapplication_{train|test}.csvの欠損値補完を行っております。
以下の2つの特徴量を平均値で埋めたいのですが、mean()の戻り値がnanになってしまいます。

特徴量
'YEARS_BUILD_AVG'
'YEARS_BEGINEXPLUATATION_AVG'

```py
print(train['YEARS_BUILD_AVG'].mean())
>>> nan
```

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

```
data['YEARS_BUILD_AVG'].fillna(data['YEARS_BUILD_AVG'].mean())
```

でうまくいきますでしょうか？